# Preg match contents between [IMG] tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm writing a script that retrieves the first image link in a post

`$content = [center]Hello World, this is my house: [img]myhouse.png[/img] blah blah blah blah [/center] This is another house [img]anotherhouse.png[/img] , blah blah blah`

I would like to just return "myhouse.png" and save it into a variable
Also `img` should be case insensitive, meaning it would work on `[img]text-here[/img]` or `[IMG]text-here[/IMG]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the first image:

```
$content = '[center]Hello World, this is my house: [img]myhouse.png[/img] blah blah blah blah [/center] This is another house [img]anotherhouse.png[/img] , blah blah blah';

preg_match('#\[img\]\s*(?P<png>.*?)\s*\[/img\]#i', $content, $m);
echo $m['png']; // myhouse.png
```

Comment: .png was just an example, it should work on all image types, sorry for not specifying that

Comment: @user2263996 png is just a "name", it will work even if you used BMP, JPG, or C++ lol :)

Comment: lol thanks, sorry i don't get how regex works, also which one should i use, this or the one above ^ ?

Comment: @user2263996 They basically do the same thing, if you upvote both answers and accept his answer I'll be satisfied :p

Comment: Thanks for your help :), i can't +1 yet, but i accepted this as answer

Comment: @user2263996 Now you can, have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a regex:

```
$content = '[center]Hello World, this is my house: [img]myhouse.png[/img] blah blah blah blah [/center] This is another house [img]anotherhouse.png[/img] , blah blah blah';

$pattern = '/\[img\](.*)\[\/img\]/U'; // <-- the U means ungreedy

preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Explanation:

The regex matches everything between a pair of `[img] ... [/img]` tags. To make sure that it will not match all text between the first `[img]` and the last [/img] tag I've use the *ungreedy* modifier.

Learn [more](http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) about PHP's regex syntax.

Comment: add the **i** modifier ! (+1) :)

Comment: After `U`, it's to make it case insensitive.

Comment: It's to match uppercased tags like: `[IMG]` as well. You can do it if you need that